# rvalue reference and setup functions

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I want to use convenience functions when creating class instances in my main() function to make things clearer.

Here is a minimal example:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
            MyClass() : value{ -1 }, str{ "hello" } {}
            MyClass( const MyClass &&other )
            {
                    value = move( other.value );
                    str = move( other.str );
                    file = move( other.file ); //Use of deleted function...
            }

            void open()
            {
                    file.open( "myfile" );
            }

    private:
            MyClass( const MyClass & ) = delete;
            MyClass operator=( const MyClass & ) = delete;
            MyClass &operator=( const MyClass && ) = delete;

            ofstream file;
            int value;
            string str;
};

inline MyClass setup_myclass()
{
    MyClass ret;
    ret.open();

    return ret;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    MyClass &&mc = setup_myclass();

    return 0;
}
```

Problem is when my class contains stuff like fstream or thread that has their move constructors deleted.

I am compiling with g++ 5.1.1 and arm-linux-g++ 5.2.0 (raspberrypi, buildroot).

What should my move constructor look like when I have members with deleted move constructors?

How can I change my code to have the same clean main function?

Comment: `std::ofstream` has a move constructor.  [it is the copy constructor that is deleted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream)

Comment: Wrong on the substance. Both std::ofstream and std::thread have move constructors. Why do you think you have a problem there? Provide compiler message.

Comment: change `MyClass( const MyClass &&other )` into `MyClass( MyClass &&other )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, your move constructor has the wrong signature:

```
MyClass( const MyClass &&other )
```

You can't move-from a `const` rvalue. You meant:

```
MyClass( MyClass &&other )
```

and more than that, you really meant:

```
MyClass( MyClass &&other ) = default;
```

See [Rule of Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). All of your members have move constructors ([`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) and [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) too!), so just use them. Similarly, this:

```
MyClass &operator=( const MyClass && ) = delete;
```

should be `public` and look like:

```
MyClass &operator=( MyClass && ) = default;
```

Why enable a move constructor but `delete` move assignment?

Secondly, this is bad:

```
MyClass &&mc = setup_myclass();
```

you just took a reference to a temporary that gets destroyed at the end of the line. You now have a dangling reference. What you want to do is just:

```
MyClass mc = setup_myclass();
```

Thanks to RVO, there will not actually be a move invoked here. The temporary within `setup_myclass()` will actually be constructed in-place in `mc`.

Comment: *"you just took a reference to a temporary that gets destroyed at the end of the line."*, doesn't binding a temporary directly to an rvalue reference extend the lifetime of that temporary?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Nope. "The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not
extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement."

Comment: Which is a nasty and sort of surprising (but not really) exception to reference-extending. I _always_ forget it.

Comment: @Barry but you get a copy of the returned value, which is a prvalue that gets bound by that reference, [isn't it?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55e094136b44e70e) you're not binding directly to that object from a return statement

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Hm, maybe that sentence is about if the return value type was a reference. Regardless, there's no reason to take `mc` as a reference. At best, it's just looks wrong. At worst, it *is* wrong.